# Easter Eggs/Hints in “Jewels of the Oracle”

Tags: jewels-of-the-oracle

In *Jewels of the Oracle* (the first one), there is a file on the CD named `JEWLHINT.MVB`. I cannot figure out what it is used for because there do not seem to be a hint function for the game. There is a part in the file that mentions has the words `MVBMP2` and `Viewer` in close proximity, but if that was a thing, it is long gone now and only useless sites mentioning a DLL can be found anymore.

Further, in the file there is also a list of room names and one of them mentions both `Hall of Order and Succession` and **`Hall of Order and Succession: "Easter Egg"`**. I can’t find anything special about that room (with the sliding number-puzzle).

Does anybody know what the file is for or how to use it. Does anybody know what the easter egg is?

Answer (score 1):

For the Easter egg, there is a bonus animation in this room according to [this website](http://www.balmoralsoftware.com/jewels/jewels.htm#1234%20Sliding). If you click on the map houses in a certain order (*as shown below*) as soon as the map is displayed, an animation moving through the centre of the model city is played. This area of the city is the same as that to which you are transported at the end of the entire game when all puzzles have been successfully solved.

Order to click on them is as follows:

1. Krida
2. Tantram
3. Kausalam
4. Paurah
5. Kavi
6. Sastram